# Edit tags button doesn't focus the tags field

Tags: bug, tags, edits, user-interface

Recently when I click the "edit tags" button and try and type the name of a tag to add, I find the tags field does not have focus, and my typing is ignored. I have to click in the tags field to start editing. It's not a big deal but it seems like some kind of UI glitch.

Currently using Firefox on a Mac.

Comment: Found a duplicate. So at least I know it's not just me.